# Null reference was unhandled C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem within my source code.
I have a file for saving my settings to an ini file. But when I want to save the settings from the main form I get an NullRefrenceExpection was unhandled exception. Where is the problem is?

**Edit**
I get the exception at this part of the code:

```
private void SaveSettings()
    {
        //SettingsIniFile iniFile = new SettingsIniFile();
        _settingsIniFile.Save(LoadTextBoxes());
    }
```

**Code Mainform:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Milk_Units
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Settings _settings;
        private SettingsIniFile _settingsIniFile;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings(false);
            LoadTextBoxes();
            LoadComportName();
        }

        private void LoadSettings(bool defaults)
        {
            SettingsIniFile iniFile = new SettingsIniFile();
            _settings = iniFile.LoadSettings(defaults);
        }

        private void SaveSettings()
        {
            //SettingsIniFile iniFile = new SettingsIniFile();
            _settingsIniFile.Save(LoadTextBoxes());
        }

        private Settings LoadTextBoxes()
        {
            //ACR
            _startRemovalTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrStartRemoval;
            _removalTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrRemovalTime;
            _removalDelayTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrRemovalDelay;
            //CLEANING
            _durCleaningTextbox.Text = _settings.CleanDurCleaning;
            _timeValveOnTextbox.Text = _settings.CleanTimeValveOn;
            _timeValveOffTextBox.Text = _settings.CleanTimeValveOff;
            //CALIBRATE
            _contentLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateContentLeft;
            _calibrateLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft;
            _contentRightTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateContentRight;
            _calibrateRightTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight;
            //CONDUCTIVITY
            _factorLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductFactorLeft;
            _offsetLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductOffsetleft;
            _factorRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductFactorRight;
            _offsetRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductOffsetRight;
            _levelLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductLevelLeft;
            _levelRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductLevelRight;
            //GENERAL
            _typeOfValveTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralTypeOfValve;
            _indicatorTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralIndicator;
            _inverseOutputTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralInverseOutput;
            _restartTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralRestartTime;
            _waterTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralWaterTime;
            _gateDelayTextbox.Text = _settings.GeneralGateDelay;
            //PULSATION
            _pulsationTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationPulsationPm;
            _ratioFrontTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrRatioFront;
            _ratioBackTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrRatioBack;
            _stimulationTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationStimulationPm;
            _stimFrontTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrStimFront;
            _stimBackTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrStimBack;
            _stimulationDurTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationStimulationDur;

            return _settings;
        }

        private void DefaultSettingButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings(true);
            LoadTextBoxes();
            SaveSettings();
            LoadComportName();
        }


        private void SendSettingsButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveSettings();
        }

        private void LoadComportName()
        {
            _comPortComboBox.DataSource = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        }

    }
```

**Code Settingsinifile**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Idento.Common.Utilities;
using Milk_Units;

namespace Milk_Units
{
    public class SettingsIniFile
    {
        private const String FileNameCustom = "Data\\Custom.ini";//Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), );
        private const String FileNameDefault = "Data\\Default.ini";//Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), );


        public Settings LoadSettings(bool defaults = false)
        {
            String fileName = defaults ? FileNameDefault : FileNameCustom;
            StringList input = new StringList().FromFile(fileName);

            //Settings settings = null;
            Settings settings = new Settings();

            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                String line = item.Trim();

                if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                    continue;

                int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();

                String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();
                String comment = "";
                index = value.IndexOf("//");
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    comment = value.Substring(index).Trim();
                    value = value.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                }

                // ACR
                if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "10: Start Removal"))
                    settings.AcrStartRemoval = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "11: Removal Time"))
                    settings.AcrRemovalTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "12: Removal Delay"))
                    settings.AcrRemovalDelay = value;
                // CLEANING
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "21: Dur. Cleaning"))
                    settings.CleanDurCleaning = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "22: Time valve on"))
                    settings.CleanTimeValveOn = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "23: Time valve off"))
                    settings.CleanTimeValveOff = value;
                //CALIBRATE
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "31: Content left"))
                    settings.CalibrateContentLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "32: Calibrate left"))
                    settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "33: Content right"))
                    settings.CalibrateContentRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "34: Calibrate right"))
                    settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight = value;
                //CONDUCTIVITY
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "41: Factor left"))
                    settings.ConductFactorLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "42: Offset left"))
                    settings.ConductOffsetleft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "43: Factor right"))
                    settings.ConductFactorRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "44: Offset right"))
                    settings.ConductOffsetRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "45: Level left"))
                    settings.ConductLevelLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "46: Level right"))
                    settings.ConductLevelRight = value;
                //GENERAL
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "51: Type of valve"))
                    settings.GeneralTypeOfValve = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "52: Indicator"))
                    settings.GeneralIndicator = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "53: Inverse output"))
                    settings.GeneralInverseOutput = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "54: Restart time"))
                    settings.GeneralRestartTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "55: Water time"))
                    settings.GeneralWaterTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "56: Gate delay"))
                    settings.GeneralGateDelay = value;
                //PULSATION
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "61: Pulsation p/m"))
                    settings.PulsationPulsationPm = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "62: S/r ratio front"))
                    settings.PulsationSrRatioFront = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "63: S/r ratio back"))
                    settings.PulsationSrRatioBack = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "64: Stimulation p/m"))
                    settings.PulsationStimulationPm = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "65: S/r stim front"))
                    settings.PulsationSrStimFront = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "66: S/r stim back"))
                    settings.PulsationSrStimBack = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "67: Stimulation dur"))
                    settings.PulsationStimulationDur = value;



            }
            return settings;
        }

        public void Save(Settings settings)
        {
            StringList list = new StringList();


            list.Add("[Settings]");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[ACR]");
            list.Add("10: Start Removal =" + settings.AcrStartRemoval + " // ms");
            list.Add("11: Removal Time  =" + settings.AcrRemovalTime + " // commentary");
            list.Add("12: Removal Delay =" + settings.AcrRemovalDelay + " // commentary");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[Cleaning]");
            list.Add("21: Dur. Cleaning =" + settings.CleanDurCleaning + " //commentary");
            list.Add("22: Time valve on =" + settings.CleanTimeValveOn + "  //commentary");
            list.Add("23: Time valve off =" + settings.CleanTimeValveOff + "    //commentary");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[Calibrate]");
            list.Add("31: Content left =" + settings.CalibrateContentLeft + "//commentary");
            list.Add("32: Calibrate left =" + settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft + "//commentary");
            list.Add("33: Content right =" + settings.CalibrateContentRight + "//commentary");
            list.Add("34: Calibrate right =" + settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight + "//commentary");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[Conductivity]");
            list.Add("41: Factor left =" + settings.ConductFactorLeft + "//commentary");
            list.Add("42: Offset left =" + settings.ConductOffsetleft + "//commentary");
            list.Add("43: Factor right =" + settings.ConductFactorRight + "//commentary");
            list.Add("44: Offset right =" + settings.ConductOffsetRight + "//commentary");
            list.Add("45: Level left =" + settings.ConductLevelLeft + "//commentary");
            list.Add("46: Level right =" + settings.ConductLevelRight + "//commentary");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[General]");
            list.Add("51: Type of valve =" + settings.GeneralTypeOfValve + "//commentary");
            list.Add("52: Indicator =" + settings.GeneralIndicator + "//commentary");
            list.Add("53: Inverse output =" + settings.GeneralInverseOutput + "//commentary");
            list.Add("54: Restart time =" + settings.GeneralRestartTime + "//commentary");
            list.Add("55: Water time =" + settings.GeneralWaterTime + "//commentary");
            list.Add("56: Gate delay =" + settings.GeneralGateDelay + "//commentary");
            list.Add("");
            list.Add("[Pulsation]");
            list.Add("61: Pulsation p/m =" + settings.PulsationPulsationPm + "//commentary");
            list.Add("62: S/r ratio front =" + settings.PulsationSrRatioFront + "//commentary");
            list.Add("63: S/r ratio back =" + settings.PulsationSrRatioBack + "//commentary");
            list.Add("64: Stimulation p/m =" + settings.PulsationStimulationPm + "//commentary");
            list.Add("65: S/r stim front =" + settings.PulsationSrStimFront + "//commentary");
            list.Add("66: S/r stim back =" + settings.PulsationSrStimBack + "//commentary");
            list.Add("67: Stimulation dur =" + settings.PulsationStimulationDur + "//commentary");


            try
            {
                list.ToFile(FileNameCustom);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception saving settings: " + exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you init `_settingsIniFile` ?

Comment: Which line is the exception is being thrown on? I'm assuming it's somewhere in LoadTextBoxes perhaps?

Comment: you meant this or did you not? private SettingsIniFile _settingsIniFile;

Comment: The line that the exepction is being thrown is under EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_settingsIniFile` member variable isn't initialized.

Have modified your code so that it intializes that member, and also in your `LoadSettings` and `SaveSettings` it refers to that member variable too.

Try this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Milk_Units
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Settings _settings;
        private SettingsIniFile _settingsIniFile = new SettingsIniFile();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings(false);
            LoadComportName();
        }

        private void LoadSettings(bool defaults)
        {
            _settings = _settingsIniFile.LoadSettings(defaults);
            LoadTextBoxes();
        }

        private void SaveSettings()
        {
            SaveTextBoxes();
            _settingsIniFile.Save(_settings);
        }

        private void LoadTextBoxes()
        {
            //ACR
            _startRemovalTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrStartRemoval;
            _removalTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrRemovalTime;
            _removalDelayTextBox.Text = _settings.AcrRemovalDelay;
            //CLEANING
            _durCleaningTextbox.Text = _settings.CleanDurCleaning;
            _timeValveOnTextbox.Text = _settings.CleanTimeValveOn;
            _timeValveOffTextBox.Text = _settings.CleanTimeValveOff;
            //CALIBRATE
            _contentLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateContentLeft;
            _calibrateLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft;
            _contentRightTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateContentRight;
            _calibrateRightTextBox.Text = _settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight;
            //CONDUCTIVITY
            _factorLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductFactorLeft;
            _offsetLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductOffsetleft;
            _factorRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductFactorRight;
            _offsetRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductOffsetRight;
            _levelLeftTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductLevelLeft;
            _levelRightTextBox.Text = _settings.ConductLevelRight;
            //GENERAL
            _typeOfValveTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralTypeOfValve;
            _indicatorTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralIndicator;
            _inverseOutputTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralInverseOutput;
            _restartTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralRestartTime;
            _waterTimeTextBox.Text = _settings.GeneralWaterTime;
            _gateDelayTextbox.Text = _settings.GeneralGateDelay;
            //PULSATION
            _pulsationTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationPulsationPm;
            _ratioFrontTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrRatioFront;
            _ratioBackTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrRatioBack;
            _stimulationTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationStimulationPm;
            _stimFrontTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrStimFront;
            _stimBackTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationSrStimBack;
            _stimulationDurTextBox.Text = _settings.PulsationStimulationDur;

            return _settings;
        }

        private void SaveTextBoxes()
        {
            //ACR
            _settings.AcrStartRemoval = _startRemovalTextBox.Text;
            _settings.AcrRemovalTime = removalTimeTextBox.Text; 
            _settings.AcrRemovalDelay = _removalDelayTextBox.Text;
            //CLEANING
            _settings.CleanDurCleaning = _durCleaningTextbox.Text;
            _settings.CleanTimeValveOn = _timeValveOnTextbox.Text;
            _settings.CleanTimeValveOff = _timeValveOffTextBox.Text;
            //CALIBRATE
            _settings.CalibrateContentLeft = _contentLeftTextBox.Text;
            _settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft = _calibrateLeftTextBox.Text;
            _settings.CalibrateContentRight = _contentRightTextBox.Text;
            _settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight = _calibrateRightTextBox.Text;
            //CONDUCTIVITY
            _settings.ConductFactorLeft = _factorLeftTextBox.Text;
            _settings.ConductOffsetleft = _offsetLeftTextBox.Text;
            _settings.ConductFactorRight = _factorRightTextBox.Text;
            _settings.ConductOffsetRight = _offsetRightTextBox.Text;
            _settings.ConductLevelLeft = _levelLeftTextBox.Text;
            _settings.ConductLevelRight = _levelRightTextBox.Text;
            //GENERAL
            _settings.GeneralTypeOfValve = _typeOfValveTextBox.Text;
            _settings.GeneralIndicator = _indicatorTextBox.Text;
            _settings.GeneralInverseOutput = _inverseOutputTextBox.Text;
            _settings.GeneralRestartTime = _restartTimeTextBox.Text;
            _settings.GeneralWaterTime = _waterTimeTextBox.Text;
            _settings.GeneralGateDelay = _gateDelayTextbox.Text;
            //PULSATION
            _settings.PulsationPulsationPm = _pulsationTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationSrRatioFront = _ratioFrontTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationSrRatioBack = _ratioBackTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationStimulationPm = _stimulationTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationSrStimFront = _stimFrontTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationSrStimBack = _stimBackTextBox.Text;
            _settings.PulsationStimulationDur = _stimulationDurTextBox.Text;
        }

        private void DefaultSettingButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings(true);
            SaveSettings();
            LoadComportName();
        }


        private void SendSettingsButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveSettings();
        }

        private void LoadComportName()
        {
            _comPortComboBox.DataSource = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        }

    }
```

Comment: That did the trick, that such a little thing can make so big of an issue.

Comment: another question, How does it come that it wont save the new added values from a textbox to the ini file. i have the ini file open in Notepad++ and that says that the file has been changted by another programm but the values stay the same. Do you know how i can fix this

Comment: oow so i have to do it like this: textbox1.Text = value

Comment: I've updated the code...simplified it a bit...hopefully a bit clearer what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where you initialise `_settingsIniFile;`

try changing your declaration to:

`private SettingsIniFile _settingsIniFile = new SettingsIniFile();`

Comment: additionally, the save area he's throwing the error on is actually calling the load function.  I don't even see where he's saving it.